# trying to modify a list conditional on the sum of the previous n entries

Tags: python, list

Essentially I have a list of 0s and 1s and I am attempting to pass through the list, adding 1 to any 1 where there has been a 1 in the previous n entries etc.

What I am hoping for at the end is a list that has 0s, 1s and 2s, where the 2s are 1s that have been modified using the condition that a 1 had appeared within the previous 10 entries.

I initially tried writing an if loop inside a for loop (looking at the previous 10 entries)but I'm not 100% sure my syntax is correct...

```
numbers = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]


for i in numbers[9:]:
  if i==1:
    if sum(numbers[i-9:i]) > 0:
      numbers[i] += 1


print(numbers)
```

The result is that when I print the list I get exactly the same numbers.. where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show what the desired result is?

Comment: You're iterating over the values of the `numbers` array rather than their index so you'll always be  comparing the same thing in the sum, `numbers[1 - 9: 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
numbers = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]

for i in range(len(numbers[9:])):
  if numbers[i]==1:
    if sum(numbers[i-9:i]) > 0:
      numbers[i] += 1

print(numbers)
```

In your question, you iterate over the values. I changed it to iterate over the indices with `range` and the length of your list.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the index of an element and its value. Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get index and value.

```
numbers = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
           1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

for index, number in enumerate(numbers[9:], start=9):
    if number == 1:
        if sum(numbers[index - 9:index]) > 0:
            numbers[index] += 1

print(numbers)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help, will use enumerate from now on.

Comment: In real code you might want to replace the `9` by a variable for maximum flexibility (and better readability).

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong at:

```py
# i here is not the index of your list, it is a value.
if sum(numbers[i-9:i]) > 0:
   numbers[i] += 1
```